# Display two pyglet window in a row

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I'm wrinting a program that sometimes has to show an obj file.
So I wrote a function (actually, I modified a code from here : https://github.com/greenmoss/PyWavefront/blob/master/example/pyglet_demo.py ) that open a pyglet window, with my rotating 3D object, and when the window is closed, the function end, and I can continue to do stuff until I have to display another (or the same) obj file.

This function works, but only the first time I call it. After that I just have a black window. So I hope someone know what I did wrong...

Here is my (a bit simplified) code:

```
import ctypes
from pyglet.gl import *

rotation = 0


def show_3d(meshes):
    window = pyglet.window.Window(1024, 720, caption='Demo')
    lightfv = ctypes.c_float * 4

    @window.event
    def on_resize(width, height):
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(60., float(width)/height, 1., 500.)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        return True

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        glLoadIdentity()

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightfv(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

        glTranslated(0, 0, -300)

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)
        glRotatef(rotation, 0, 1, 0)

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        meshes.draw()

    def update(dt):
        global rotation
        rotation += 60*dt

    pyglet.clock.schedule(update)
    pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pywavefront import Wavefront
    mesh = Wavefront("path to a .obj")
    show_3d(mesh)  # awesome 3D animation
    # some stuff
    show_3d(mesh)  # just a black window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, but I guess this isn't the perfect answer.

The first problem is that the "on_resize" is only called once in the entire program.
So I duplicate the code in that function into the main one.

I had to keep the on_resize function, because if i don't, it's the first call to show_3d that display nothing (?).

Second problem is that with more call of show_3d (let's say 5), my animation is going faster and faster. It should not be, because I already use the dt parameter in "update" to ensure that it's not the case.

To make it work, I tried  pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60), and pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60). But none of that lines worked.
So I made my own "dt" with call to time.time().
Now it is working

```
import ctypes
from pyglet.gl import *
from time import time

rotation = 0
t0 = time()    

def show_3d(meshes):
    window = pyglet.window.Window(1024, 720, caption='Demo')
    lightfv = ctypes.c_float * 4
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(60., float(1024)/720, 1., 500.)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    @window.event
    def on_resize(width, height):
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(60., float(width)/height, 1., 500.)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        return True

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        glLoadIdentity()

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightfv(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

        glTranslated(0, 0, -300)

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK)
        glRotatef(rotation, 0, 1, 0)

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        meshes.draw()

    def update(dt):
        global rotation
        global t0

        dt = time()-t0
        t0 = time()
        rotation += 60*dt

    pyglet.clock.schedule(update)
    pyglet.app.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pywavefront import Wavefront
    mesh = Wavefront("path to a .obj")
    show_3d(mesh)  # awesome 3D animation
    # some stuff
    show_3d(mesh)  # awesome 3D animation
```